# How to Write data to Sql Table from SharePoint WebPart when DB and SP are on different machine?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sharepoint, sql-server-2008-r2, sharepoint-2013

I am working on SharePoint 2013. Database is on SqlServer 2008R2. Both SP and DB are on different machines. I am creating a webPart which is associated with usercontrol. I'm writing the logic in cs file of usercontrol, to write data collected from the form into Data table of sql server.

```
Connection string: Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User
Id=myUsername; Password=myPassword;
```

But it is failing and throwing an error like "Login failed for user".

Please guide.

Comment: Does your database allow mixed mode authentication?  If it doesn't, your database will not allow you to use the username and password you supplied.

Comment: It's in mixed mode. Supports both Sql as well windows authentication.

Comment: Can you log in with the username and password using SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Yes. I'm able to login.

Comment: Perhaps posting the full code will help in this case.  Either you have the wrong username and or password or somewhere in the code, something isn't right.  I don't know what else could be happening with the information posted.

Comment: I'll post the code soon. Only Connection string is required? Username and password are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into the [Double Hop Problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knowledgecast/archive/2007/01/31/the-double-hop-problem.aspx) [(also see why NTLM fails)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/besidethepoint/archive/2010/05/09/double-hop-authentication-why-ntlm-fails-and-kerberos-works.aspx). To know for sure use [ULSViewer](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer) to drill into the SharePoint Error details. From the SQL side check [the default trace](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlsakthi/archive/2011/02/06/how-to-troubleshoot-connectivity-failure-error-with-sql-server.aspx). "default trace gives you the reason for login failure in plain English"

If it is the double hop causing the error, you may want to look into [configuring Kerberos](http://www.harbar.net/archive/2010/03/31/sharepoint-2010-and-kerberos.aspx) or switching to using an External List instead of a web part and using the [Secure Store Service with BCS](http://sympmarc.com/2013/04/10/setting-up-bcs-and-the-secure-store-service-in-sharepoint-2010/).

Comment: He's specifying the username and password.  Double hop would only be in play if he was using a trusted connection.

Comment: That may be true, but either way, he should check the ULS logs and SQL Default Trace. In the long run, he'd probably be better off checking out Kerberos, Secure Store Service and BCS for database connections.